# Can't interact with external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, dock

I have a MacBook Air 2015 and I want to use it with an external monitor and a hard drive. In order to do that, I connected the computer to a docking station Dell D3100.

I downloaded the drivers from DisplayLink's website, the one I used was the driver that works with OS High Sierra (`DisplayLink USB Graphics Software for Mac OS X and macOS4.3.1-EXE.dmg`).

I turned on the docking station and connected it to my laptop, then I could see another desktop on my external monitor but the problem I have is that I can't interact with it. The monitor shows the shaded menu at the top and one pdf file.

I organized the screens vertically through **System Preferences** > **Displays** > **Alignment**

I think I'm close to fixing this issue I just need help with the last step.

Comment: It sounds like you have the option "Displays have separate Spaces" enabled in System Preferences -> Desktop & Dock.

Comment: the option I have when I select the icon at the top that is a rectangle with a triangle  at the bottom ( [ ^ ], is "use as an independent display", Is that what you are saying?

Comment: What version of MacOS are you using (you mention that the driver works with High Sierra, is that what you're running)? I'm referring to a setting in Ventura, I don't remember what the equivalent in HS was.

Comment: But I'm referring to a setting related to Spaces, not Displays.

Comment: I have High Sierra 10.13.6 and downloaded driver DisplayLink macOS Software Version: 4.3.1 (206) released on  October 2nd, 2018  I will try following the instructions recommended here to see if it works https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1854724-how-to-enable-an-extended-displaylink-display-on-m

Comment: It worked, I uninstall the driver I had and followed the instructions from the article I shared, then I connected the docking station and now I can interact with the external screen. Thanks for helping me process the solution through your comments